# CollectionView reload data?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view to load a couple of photos just like Instagram posts but every time it reloads the data using `collectionView?.reloadData()`, all the photos in the collection view are rearranged. The order is showing in different positions in the collection view. When you refresh the data you can see the first photo in the first position. Go to the last position, then other photos are have also changed positions. This happens even if there is no change to the photo and all the photos are the same. I am wondering why it's happened like that?

Comment: Is the order of images you supply to the collectionview the same as before when you reload the data?

Comment: are you using array for supply data in collection view ??

Comment: Yes, i am using array i first store all images in the array then show the image in cellForItemAt indexPath. Its hard to say what the issues is but just when you reload the data all the images just shuffling the position really fast like one sec then back to their position suppose to be.

Answer (score 0):

First, add your all images in the array and then show in CollectionView. Then your images not change place.